# Fitted line, data points with different weights

Tags: r

I want to try and fit a 'line of best fit' in R to a set of points. But I want each point to carry a specific weight based upon the precision of that point.

My data is:

```
x  y   precision
4  4   2
16 18  5
17 39  4
29 30  20
38 38  11
```

So I want the line to fit the points with the higher precision more than it would fit the point with the lower precision.

I'm guessing it is something along the lines of:

```
abline(lm(y~x+precision))
```

This doesn't seem to work though
Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then you need to use the `weights` argument in the `lm` function to do that:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text='x  y   precision
4  4   2
16 18  5
17 39  4
29 30  20
38 38  11')

a <- lm( y ~ x , data=df , weights=precision)

> a

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = df, weights = precision)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
    10.7895       0.7096
```

As you can see this is different to the result you would get if you didn't use the `weights` argument:

```
> a <- lm( y ~ x , data=df)
> a

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
     7.5893       0.8755
```

This way each point is given a specific weight according to the precision value.

And just so you know exactly how `weights` works, it replicates each row as many times as the `weights` vector dictates (in this case precision). i.e.

```
df2 <- read.table(header=T, text='x  y   precision
4  4   2
4  4   2
16 18  5
16 18  5
16 18  5
16 18  5
16 18  5
17 39  4
17 39  4
17 39  4
17 39  4
29 30  20
29 30  20
29 30  20
29 30  20
29 30  20
29 30  20
29 30  20
29 30  20
29 30  20
29 30  20
29 30  20
29 30  20
29 30  20
29 30  20
29 30  20
29 30  20
29 30  20
29 30  20
29 30  20
29 30  20
38 38  11
38 38  11
38 38  11
38 38  11
38 38  11
38 38  11
38 38  11
38 38  11
38 38  11
38 38  11
38 38  11')

b <- lm( y ~ x , data=df2)

> b

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = df2)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
    10.7895       0.7096
```

As you can see the result is exactly the same as applying precision as the `weights` argument.

So that you know exactly how the `weights` argument works!

Answer (score 0):

As you are also asking about visualizing these.

`abline()` requires a call to `plot()` beforehand. This should be a scatterplot of x and y as otherwise just the line plot does not contain any useful information.

To visualise that your regression line is based on a weighted regression you could put in another line for the model with equal weighting and/or make point sizes dependent on precision.

See below for a simple example:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text='x  y   precision
4  4   2
16 18  5
17 39  4
29 30  20
38 38  11')

u <- lm( y ~ x , data=df)
w <- lm( y ~ x , data=df, weights=precision)

plot(df$x, df$y, cex=df$precision/max(df$x)*10)
abline(u, lty=2)
abline(w)
```

However, note that use of circles is frowned upon by some because humans have trouble comparing their sizes. I'm sure there are discussions of this on stackexchange. An example of this is the 'Ebbinghaus illusion' (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebbinghaus_illusion)